# Adding spaces and Commas to Array result set being echo'd or saved

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

Can anyone please help me with adding spaces and commas to the below, currently my result set will print something like this:

> TestNameOneTestSurnameOneTestNameTwoTestSurnameTwoTestNameThreeTestSurnameThreeTestNameFourTestSurnameFourTestNameFiveTestSurnameFive

My ideal result set would be:

> TestNameOne TestSurnameOne, TestNameTwo TestSurnameTwo, TestNameThree TestSurnameThree, TestNameFour TestSurnameFour, TestNameFive TestSurnameFive

Code:

```
$ctr = 0;
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $RespondentsResultSetArray[$ctr] = array(
        "Firstname" => $row['cnt_firstname'],
        "Lastname" => $row['cnt_lastname']
    );

    $ctr = $ctr + 1;
}

foreach ($RespondentsResultSetArray as $key) {
    echo ($key["Firstname"]);
    echo ($key["Lastname"]);
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
```

I'm going to be inserting this code into a word document template (one bookmark), I have already defined that process with just one result and only name (example: Joe) but I will need to insert all of the above correctly appended into the bookmark in the word template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use concatenation

```
foreach ($RespondentsResultSetArray as $key) {
    echo $key["Firstname"].' '.$key["Lastname"].', ';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

```
    $ctr = 0;
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $RespondentsResultSetArray[$ctr] = array(
            "Firstname" => $row['cnt_firstname'],
            "Lastname" => $row['cnt_lastname']
        );

        $ctr++;
    }

   $My_Complete_String = "";
   foreach ($RespondentsResultSetArray as $key) {

       $My_Complete_String .=$key["Firstname"])." ".$key["Lastname"].",";
    }

    rtrim($My_Complete_String, ",");
    echo $My_Complete_String;

    sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
```